# What DLC is included in borderlands 2 season pass, and what is not included

Tags: borderlands-2

I cannot find a clear list anywhere of what exactly is and what is not included  in the Borderlands 2 Season Pass.

Answer (score 30):

- Captain Scarlett and Her Pirate's Booty
- Mr. Torgue's Campaign of Carnage
- Sir Hammerlock's Big Game Hunt
- Ultimate Vault Hunter Upgrade Pack
- Tiny Tina's Assault on Dragon Keep

Psycho Pack, Mechromancer Pack and others are not included in the Season Pass

[source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borderlands_2#Downloadable_content)

Comment: I got the Mechromancer from the Seasons Pass.

Comment: @Sabre are you sure? If you pre-ordered the game, you got it for free. Otherwise it's $10 / 800 MS Points.

Answer (score 6):

As of now (2013/05/16 10:14:20 CST), the following Borderlands 2 DLC has been released:

- Psycho Pack
- Ultimate Vault Hunter's Upgrade Pack
- Sir Hammerlock's Big Game Hunt
- Mr. Torgue's Campaign of Carnage
- Mechromancer Pack
- Captain Scarlett and her Pirate's Booty
- Borderlands 2 Collector's Edition Pack
- Creature Slaughterdome
- ... and numerous skin/head packs

Having purchased the Season Pass, I can tell you that the following DLC is part of the Season Pass:

- Sir Hammerlock's Big Game Hunt
- Mr. Torgue's Campaign of Carnage
- Captain Scarlett and her Pirate's Booty
- Ultimate Vault Hunter's Upgrade Pack
- Tiny Tina's Assault on Dragon Keep

And you get extra 11 levels!

Comment: Ultimate Vault Hunter's Upgrade Pack is part of the season pass too

Comment: Hmmm... I had that earlier. Must've deleted it on accident when I removed Mechromancer from the `included` list.

Comment: You might have forgotten the most recent one. Tiny Tina's Assault on Dragon Keep

Comment: @deutschZuid That hasn't been released yet and so I didn't put it on the list.

Comment: @Yamus no prob :).