# What Borderlands 2 DLC is required to get 100% achievements?

Tags: achievements, borderlands-2

If someone could build on [What DLC is included in borderlands 2 season pass, and what is not included](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/117454/what-dlc-is-included-in-borderlands-2-season-pass-and-what-is-not-included), what DLC is required to 100% Borderlands 2?

For instance, does the base game + seasons pass suffice, or are additional DLC that aren't included like the Creature Slaughterdome required for some achievements?

Comment: This is a little urgent since it's on a 66% off steam flash sale for the next 6 hours and it might not happen again for a long time.

Comment: Regardless of what you need for 100%, I would strongly recommend getting all the DLC, as Borderlands 2 is an excellent game.

Comment: @SaintWacko That's kind of silly, not just anyone can afford to spend $15 on classes that hardly change the campaign much less $34 on character skins which don't change the game at all.

Comment: Ooh. I forgot they sell non-gameplay DLC now. Sorry about that, I meant just the actual gameplay DLC.

Comment: By techinical default, you don't even need to get DLC to get all the achievements. Steam Achievement Manager can actually do that all for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thus far, the only DLC needed are the four campaign DLCs (Captain Scarlett and her Pirate's Booty, Mr. Torgue’s Campaign of Carnage, Sir Hammerlock’s Big Game Hunt, and Tiny Tina's Assault on Dragon Keep, all included in the Season Pass). The Mechromancer Pack, Psycho pack, Ultimate Vault Hunter's Upgrade Pack, Collector's Edition Pack, Creature Slaughterdome, and various outfit packs have no achievements.

If Gearbox continue to release DLC, this is almost certainly the pattern they will follow; DLC which adds a significant amount of new quests will include achievements, DLC which does not (new characters, skins, items or smaller content like the slaughter dome) will not.